# OOP PHP Safe Project

Tags: php, html, oop

I have this "safe" project to get the basics down just to become more familiar with OOP.

Here is my code:

**chest.php**

```
<?php
    class safe{

        public $isLocked = true;
        public $isClosed = true;

        public function unlock(){

            if ($this->isLocked == true) {

                $this->isLocked = false;
                echo "Safe Unlocked<br>";

            }else{

                echo "Safe Already Unlocked<br>";

            }

        }

        public function lock(){

            if ($this->isLocked == false) {

                if ($this->isClosed == true) {

                    $this->isLocked = true;
                    echo "Safe Now Locked<br>";

                }else{

                    echo "Safe Needs To Be Closed To Be Locked<br>";

                }



            }else{

                echo "Safe Is Already Locked<br>";

            }

        }

        public function checkLock(){

            if ($this->isLocked == true) {

                echo "<span style='color:red;'>Safe Is Locked</span><br>";

            }else{

                echo "<span style='color:red;'>Safe Is Not Locked</span><br>";

            }

        }

        public function open(){

            if ($this->isClosed == true) {

                if ($this->isLocked == false) {

                    $this->isClosed = false;
                    echo "Safe Is Now Open<br>";

                }else{

                    echo "Safe Is Locked, Cannot Open<br>";

                }

            }else{

                echo "Safe Already Open<br>";

            }

        }

        public function close(){

            if ($this->isClosed == false) {

                if ($this->isLocked == false) {

                    $this->isClosed = true;
                    echo "Safe Now Closed<br>";

                }else{

                    echo "Safe Is Currently Locked Cannot Close<br>";

                }

            }else{

                echo "Safe Already Closed<br>";

            }

        }
    }
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
    require 'chest.php';

    $safe = new safe();

    if ($safe->isLocked == true) {

        echo "Safe Currently Locked<br><br>";
    }

    $safe->open();
    $safe->lock();
    $safe->unlock();
    $safe->open();
    $safe->lock();
    $safe->open();
    $safe->unlock();
    $safe->checkLock();
    $safe->lock();
    $safe->close();
    $safe->lock();
    $safe->open();
    $safe->lock();
    $safe->checkLock();

    if (isset($_POST['unlock'])) {

            $safe->unlock();

        }
        if (isset($_POST['lock'])) {

            $safe->lock();

        }
        if (isset($_POST['open'])) {

            $safe->open();

        }
        if (isset($_POST['close'])) {

            $safe->close();

        }
        if (isset($_POST['check'])) {

            $safe->checkLock();

        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Safe</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="unlock" value="Unlock">
            <input type="submit" name="lock" value="Lock">
            <input type="submit" name="open" value="Open">
            <input type="submit" name="close" value="Close">
            <input type="submit" name="check" value="Check Lock">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It works fine when I call the functions without the `if` statement, but when I try to put them into an `isset($_POST['value']` it keeps displaying only 1 output and always sets `isLocked();` back to being true so it never works.

Comment: Interesting...very interesting....what's the question?

Comment: Maybe you don't pass any parameter via `POST` (params not in URL, but via header)

Comment: The lock constantly is locked, when I click unlock it spits out "Unlocked" but it just then resets straight to locked. But it doesn't do this when I manually enter $safe->unlock();

Comment: maybe you should try var_dump($_POST['value']). ISSET might not be a good fit, as isset($var) where $var = false would evaluate to true. 
Since all vars in your form would get submitted, all your if statements are evaluating to true.
You should be more specific (if(isset($_POST['value']) && $_POST['value'] == 1).

Comment: So ive figured out that its because its refreshing the page every time I press a button, does anyone know how to stop a page from refreshing after i click submit, or would i be reaching out of PHP to make this happen..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the page from refreshing each time would require javascript and ajax. Your javascript could stop the page from loading on click, and your ajax could make a call to the server to execute your PHP

Comment: If you use jQuery, try:
$('button').on('input[type="submit"]', function(){
    $.post('/URL', { $(this).attr('name') : $(this).attr('value') }, function(data)
{
    //check response to make sure it succeeded
}
});